# Потеря фокуса после удаления сфокусированного элемента

Tags: html, javascript

Что происходит, когда удаляется (или становится hidden) элемент, имеющий фокус? Элементы и действия приведшие к удалению могут быть разные. Нужно продолжать отслеживать события клавиатуры после удаления сфокусированного элемента. Как это сделать? Пробовал повесить обработчик `onkeydown` на `<body>` или `<html>`, но события не приходят. Или можно как-то сделать, чтобы после удаления элемента фокус передавался другому существующему элементу? Достаточно только для браузеров, поддерживающих HTML5/CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

ну если ты скрываешь элемент строкой `el.style.display='none'`,так почему потом не написать `other_element.focus()`

[focus](http://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur)

Comment: Понятно, что есть функция `focus`. Но у меня много разных элементов и действий с ними. Понятно, что можно в каждый обработчик (где сейчас последней строчкой скрываем элемент) дописать `focus`. Но потом элементы с подобной логикой будут добавляться еще.